# How to make an if else syntax with datetime (time only)

Tags: vb.net, time

Need your help guys, how can I make an if else with time? I just need to make the time and minutes to round off.

for example: I put 9:23 in a textbox

```
if textbox1.text >= 9:00 And textbox1.text <= 9:30
textbox1.text = 9:00
end if


It will round off to 9:00, I just need the syntax on how the time will round off. Thank you 3000
```

Comment: If it's a WinForms or WPF project, you can use a DateTimePicker/TimePicker that show time only. You can then compare the selected `.Value`. Or you could use [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse) to compare the converted strings values to a base DateTime. For example: `Dim baseTime as Date = Date.Now.Date + new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0) Dim userTime as Date = Date.Parse(textbox1.text) If userTime > baseValue AndAlso userTime < baseValue.AddMinutes(30) then (...) End If`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim datetime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textbox1.text)
Dim timeininteger As Integer = CInt(datetime.ToString("mm"))

If timeininteger >= 0 And timeininteger <= 30 Then
    textbox1.text = datetime.ToString("HH:" & "00")
End If
```

Comment: One last sir, about the else part. if it's not >=0 and <=30 how can I add 1 hour in the hour? for example i added 9:31 in the textbox it will convert to 10:00. Sorry i forgot and thank you so much 3000 :D

Comment: Use Dim currenthour as Integer = CInt(datetime.ToString("HH")) to get hour. Then, textbox1.text = "currenthour:00"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you see, `9:30` isn't time. Not to a computer, at least. It's a string. So you'll need to format it until it's time.

I notice that you didn't specify AM or PM, so I'll assume that you're using a 24h time format. Here we go:

```
'Convert the text from the TextBox1 to DateTime
Dim time As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textbox1.text)

'Here's the result:
MessageBox.Show(time.ToShortTimeString)

'You can get only one component of a DateTime:
MessageBox.Show(time.Hour.ToString)

'So, yeah, you can totally do math with time now! Look:
If time.Minute > 30 Then
    MessageBox.Show((time.Hour + 1).ToString)
End If
```

Now that you master time, use your newfound powers for the greater good!

Comment: Yes Sir, it's a 24h time format. Thank you so much sir, but one last thing sir, the message box includes only the hour, how can I add the minutes that has been round off to :00? for example 10:00.

Comment: If you're using an IDE with intellisense (like Visual Studio), try exploring your options by writing `time.`, and you'll see that most of the work has already been done for you. So, if you want "hh:mm", you can call it easily: `time.ToString("H:mm")`

Comment: `time.Hour` and the like will give you not Strings but numbers you can do arithmetic with. It's really useful!

Comment: Lastly, if you want to do arithmetic AND get a string, you con combine these: `MessageBox.Show((time.Hour + 1).ToString("H:mm"))`. Life is good.